# When calling Image.LoadFile, how to distinguish a bad file from being out of memory?

Tags: c#, .net, image

If I call Image.LoadFile with a bad file, the function [is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to throw an instance of OutofMemoryException.

When catching this exception, how can my code distinguish a bad file from being actually out of memory?

Supplementary question: Why OutOfMemoryException of all things?

Comment: Because usually a corrupt image ends up being corrupt in ways that says that it has 2 bajillion pixels times 17 gazillion pixels with 24 permillion bytes per pixel.

Comment: This API is based on GDI+ which can only communicate errors using an integer error code. That causes very undescriptive error messages. Using OOM as an error code in particular is a bug/design flaw.

Comment: GDI+ error codes and, above all, the codecs it uses are not sophisticated enough to provide decent exceptions.  Just report the exception message as-is, don't try to attach any extra meaning to them.  Your user will have *very* little trouble googling it or using an image viewer to check out the file.  The end result is the same, no matter what you do or what you say, that image isn't going to get loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant - Its the difference between HTTP 4xx (your fault) and 5xx (my fault) errors. A bad file is the user's fault. Being out of memory is the server's fault.

Comment: Hmya, the MSDN Forums server constantly fell over with 500 errors.  Never got fixed.  I got fed up with it and switched to SO.  Same advice applies here, if you don't like the api then don't use it.  WIC is a better mousetrap.